# how to update .net windows application through internet

Tags: .net, windows, executable

hey guys,
i have a .net windows based application, now once i give the application to the client, is there any way i can update the application given to the client through internet, i mean i have a website, whenever client run my application, application should first take updates from the url specified and then it should start, so that i dont have to go to client everytime for any updations, is there any way like this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a .net program update itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609957/how-can-a-net-program-update-itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google ClickOnce. Pretty easy to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem might be solved using [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Making a dotnet client application update itself over internet can be done in two ways (i know of)

Microsoft has something they call [clickonce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) that, IIRC, works over internet.

It isn't that hard to roll your own though.  You have a startup exe which does the checking and downloads a new main exe when needed.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use ClickOnce you can have a look at [codeplex NetSparkle AutoUpdate for .NET](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/documentation), a class library that handles this for you.