# running code after application is closed?

Tags: vb.net

i have the following problem. i am working on an auto update in my application which means i want to re-download the application. i am using DownloadFile method for this but the problem is of course i cannot download and exchange the file with my current application as long as the application is running and i can't run code after it's closed either.

this is what i am basically trying to do for ppl still didn't get my problem:

```
Private Sub closeApp()
    Application.Exit()
    ' DOWNLOAD FILE AFTER PROGRAM CLOSED
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you download it then close? Your update should detect if it's running and prompt the user to close it so ***it can update***

Comment: i can't download the file (and replace it under the same name) as long as my program is opened up.

Comment: You dont make it a different name...

Comment: but this is exactly what i don't want. i want to replace the current .exe with the updated one. who wants something like Program.exe and then the updated version as ProgramUpdated.exe

Comment: You ***don't***. Download the update, the update should prompt the user and instance is running and they should close it to update...

Comment: Are you saying that every other application out there has different application names, **no** When they update, they usually check for this kind of stuff...

Comment: my only problem is that i can't run code when the program is closed or at least i don't know how. maybe i don't understand you either i am sorry for that if that's the case

Comment: Im voting to close this question as it's too broad to answer here. There are to many possible answers that could be submitted, but with the code you have shown, doesn't have anything to do with what you are asking. If you edit your post to include all necessary details we may be of help...

Comment: Also if you done some research maybe this would have been some help: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636096/vb-net-program-should-auto-update**. There are many answer's already out that do exactly what you want to do. If you get stuck come back and we would be glad to assist you.

Comment: thanks for your help, i'll check that out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1609957/62576

Answer (score 0):

The way this is usually done is to have 2 separate programs.  One is the program its self, the other is the updater.  When you exit the program you spin up a copy of the updater and exit the actual program.  the updater program is then free to download and overwrite the main application because the file isn't in use any more.

This can also be reversed, with the updater, sometimes called the "launcher" when used this way, acting as a stub that checks for updates to the main application when it starts.  Once it sees that no update is needed, or after it updates the main program, it goes on to launch the main program and exits its self.

Comment: Just to add two things to the above that may help/provide a bit of flexibility in your approach: 1. You can replace a program even in Program Files, with one with the same name and Windows won't revert it. 2. You can rename a program on disk even when an instance of it is running.